# Does realm.io database support real-time sync?

Tags: android, synchronization, firebase-realtime-database, realm, real-time

I'm considering switching from Firebase DB to Realm.io for my Android app.

I wonder - does Realm make any guarantees about real-time sync?

From what I found:

> "Data sync will automatically happen whenever you save, with no work from you."

That sounds like a start, but there is no mention of the speed of this...

Will it be real-time like in Firebase DB, or more of a slow "poll-based" process?

Comment: Realm's sync is realtime (push, not poll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm is able to provide real-time synchronization, as long as you set up a Realm Object Server (ROS).

Synchronization itself (between devices and to the ROS, through the ROS) is free, you just need to have a ROS somewhere.

As for listening to events and reading from/writing to the *synchronized* Realm on the server side using the NodeJS API, that's the paid feature.

You can write to the sync database manually on the server-side with the Realm Browser, though; which runs on Mac OS.

---

(I don't think it's worth a mention, but obviously you can write into sync Realms from Android devices and stuff. It's just the server-side that's not as simple.)